# Should I add a property in domain model just for entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm attempting to synthesize what I've been reading about domain driven design and the entity framework model-first capabilities.  I have an existing database, but I ignored that while I created my domain model.  I ended up with a Company class and a Person class.  In the model, I have no need for a relationship between the two classes.  However, I do need a way to get a list of the people at a company.  I decided that I would have a GetPeople(int companyId) method on my PersonRepository, so that I wouldn't have to have a Company instance in order to get this list.  The classes look like this:

**Company Class**
int Id
string Name

**Person Class**
int Id
string FirstName
string LastName

**PersonRepository**
IEnumerable`<Person>` GetPeople(int companyId) { ? }

Now to the database/EF part.  In the database, I have a basic foreign-key relationship, so the tables look just like the classes above, except that the Persons table also has a CompanyId field.

Since I haven't added any reference to this database relationship in the domain model, EF has no idea that the classes are related, and so when I go to write the GetPeople method, I can't do this...

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(int companyId) {
   return MyDbContext.Persons.Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId);
}
```

...because there is no CompanyId property on the Person class in the domain model.  I can always add that property, but then the persistence mechanism is now influencing my domain model, which seems to be what you want to avoid with a model-first approach.

Does adding that property incorrectly intrude on the domain model, or is it not an improper intrusion because it's still just a POCO?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to accomplish...

You could add an Employees table/object that ties the Company ID and Person ID together.

With that you can get the Employees for a particular Company, or get the Company that a particular Person works for.

Comment: I've already got a CompanyId in the Person table (but not the class), so the are tied together in the database.  It's just that EF doesn't know about it, since there's no CompanyId on the Person class.

Comment: Per your statement, the CompanyId is a property of the Person, so should be reflected in the Person object. You could add an Employees object that combines the IDs of both and manages the lookup of CompanyEmployees or PersonWorksFor.